Azure Application Insight all events not being logged- C#
Azure Application Insight all events not being logged- C#
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {    
         AzureHelper.LogEvent("Event1");//Static Method, logging Event1
         AzureHelper.LogEvent("Event2");//Static Method, logging Event2
         UpdateInformation();//Static Method working
         AzureHelper.LogEvent("Event3");//Not being logged     
 }


//Azure Helper class

 public static void LogEvent(string data)
 {
     try
     {
         telemetryClient.TrackEvent(data);
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Exception in AppInsight" + e.Message);
     }
 }

I tried logging the event within the UpdateInformation() as well, there also its not working. I feel like after UpdateInformation(), appinsight is losing context.

What is the version of your App? How you have configured Application Inisghts?

If possible please share your code repro.

That is probably due to the fact that the application has ended before the telemetry is emitted. Application Insights buffers the telemetry and sends it to the Azure backend once in a while.
You can try flushing telemetry with telemetryClient.FlushAsync():
static async Task Main(string[] args)
 {    
         AzureHelper.LogEvent("Event1");//Static Method, logging Event1
         AzureHelper.LogEvent("Event2");//Static Method, logging Event2
         UpdateInformation();//Static Method working
         AzureHelper.LogEvent("Event3");//Not being logged  
         
         await telemetryClient.FlushAsync();
 }

